# LLD - unknown argument: -arch

Tags: c++, macos, linker, llvm, lld

Trying to link a simple program using LLVM 4.0.0 release (Clang, LLD) on Mac OS Sierra.
Note, this is fully achievable in Linux.

My current path is prefixed with the LLVM's `bin` directory (i.e. `/opt/LLVM/4.0.0/bin:$PATH`.

The program (`main.cpp`) is the simplest possible C++ application:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The shell command issued is: `clang -fuse-ld=lld`.
This fails with these errors:

```
/opt/llvm/4/bin/ld.lld: error: unknown argument: -no_deduplicate
/opt/llvm/4/bin/ld.lld: error: unknown argument: -dynamic
/opt/llvm/4/bin/ld.lld: error: unknown argument: -arch
/opt/llvm/4/bin/ld.lld: error: unknown emulation: acosx_version_min
/opt/llvm/4/bin/ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lto_library
/opt/llvm/4/bin/ld.lld: error: /opt/llvm/4/lib/libLTO.dylib: invalid data encoding
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Using the `-v` switch, I see this linker command (formatted):

```
"/opt/llvm/4/bin/ld.lld" \
    -demangle \
    -lto_library /opt/llvm/4/lib/libLTO.dylib \
    -no_deduplicate \
    -dynamic \
    -arch x86_64 \
    -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 \
    -o a.out \
    main.o \
    -lSystem /opt/llvm/4/bin/../lib/clang/4.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Does anyone know the proper switches for this platform?

Comment: you ever figure this out?

Comment: @bogardon yes. I contacted the Clang mailing list.
Work on LLD for macOS (meaning, the Mach-O object format) is stale.
Best way to go for now is to keep with the system linker (I believe it's called `ld64`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting the LLVM-dev mailing list, it appears that LLD for macOS (meaning, Mach-O object format linking) development is stale.

To use Clang on macOS, it's best to stick with the OS-provided `ld64`.

Comment: is ld64 the same as /usr/bin/ld? I wanted to use lld for the faster link times. I guess it's not possible yet?

Comment: Yes, I think they may actually be symlinked.
Note, you CAN use LLD on macOS, but:
1. The 'bindings' to link automatically after compiling (clang -fuse-ld=lld) are broken in macOS. You would need to compile only, then link in a separate command.
1. According to the LLVM dev list, the linker itself is in pre-alpha quality, so for now, it's only for experimental stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason to use LLVM-lld is speed, then try zld

- https://github.com/michaeleisel/zld/

It's consistently cuts time to half (often to less than half) as compared to that taken by Apple-ld.

Add the following linker flag:

```
-fuse-ld=`which zld` -Wl,-zld_original_ld_path,ld
```